# Grep for http not https

Tags: linux, http, https, grep

I've moved a site over from http to https and (as expected) i'm getting a few errors - What i'm looking to do is grep for anything that references http not https, is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways I can think of in the order I would try:

1)

```
$ grep -i 'http[^s]' *
```

2) I'm assuming the logs would be something of the sort : http://some.site.com or https://some.site.com. So grep for 'http:'

```
$ grep -i 'http:' *
```

3) Grep for http and remove https from results :

```
$ grep -i http * | grep -v https
```

Comment: In this particular case it may even be easier to just grep for `http://`